# What kind of super strong bonding agent would be useful to repair a stiletto heel?

Tags: glue

Fiancee broke her shoe I bought her. Gucci told me tough luck.  Cobbler told me it's unfixable.  Before I throw these way too expensive shoes in the trash, I figured I'd give it one shot to attempt a repair.  The metal post is still intact that runs down the center of the heel.

I'm considering drilling very small holes into the white part shown in the photo to increase the strength of the bonding agent.  Any suggestions on what to use?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this is off-topic.

Comment: because it's not about a house?

Comment: Correct (15 ch)

Comment: shoes are not home improvement. Yes, because.....  this is a serious site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cobbler told you it was unfixable, it's most likely unfixable. The picture you linked is too small to see much detail, but if you have a question about glue I always recommend [This to That](http://www.thistothat.com/) as a good place to look up what kind of glue to use.

But honestly, I don't think any glue is going to hold this in the way you want. The shoes are most likely dead. If they're expensive enough you can look at a home insurance claim, but I doubt that's a route you want to go!